# Differentiating between Water and Built-Up pixels in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, classification, land-classification

I am classifying an imagery that has 3 bands i.e., `NIR`, `Red`, and `Green band`.

While classifying I am not able to differentiate between `Water` and `Built-up` pixels and there is lot cross contamination irrespective of method of classification.

Is there any method to handle such problem using band operations?

**RGB Composite**

[image]

**Classified image**
*builtup in blue, which indicates water erroneously*

[image]

**EDIT:** Inserted images

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to focus on **one** software package. Specifying two packages in the title makes this question *too broad*.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating between built-up and water classes should be very achievable, especially with the nIR band available. Electromagnetic radiation (EMR) is highly absorbed in the nIR portion of the spectrum. On the other hand, built up areas commonly have high reflectance, especially if there is exposed soil.

Here are the likely situations leading to your poor classification accuracy:

1. Your training data is poor. You may need to reacquire the training
   data, making sure to select pure pixels in your classes of interest.
2. The water has a high level of healthy green vegetation such as algae
   or aquatic vegetation--both of which will reflect EMR in the nIR 
   portion of the spectrum.

If you continue to have issues, I would recommend using Landsat-8 or Sentinel-2 satellite imagery. The additional spectral bands will be useful for handling mixed pixels often found in built-up areas.

Comment: I am using LISS-IV image of Resourcesat - 2 satellite that has higher spatial resolution (5 m) but only 3 bands i.e., nIR, Red, and Green. Given the high resolution, built-up and water should be distinguishable, but many of the built up area gets into water. The DN values for these two classes are VERY similar, I do not know why.

Comment: What do you mean by the buildup areas get into water? Could you post a screenshot showing the problem areas?

Comment: I have inserted images.